# Grouping by year - mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL database with a date field.

I need to find what years are in the entries.

For example. If there are 5 entries which are in 2014, and 1 in 2015. I would like 2014 and 2015 output.

I think this needs to be done by `GROUP BY` which I have tried. I am just now not sure how to complete an inner query, which is what I think needs to be done.

```
SELECT field_id_34 AS start_date
FROM exp_channel_data
WHERE channel_id = 5
GROUP BY YEAR(field_id_34)
```

Can someone tell me if this is what needs to be done? and possibly how?

Comment: I didn`t downvote you,but this is really unclear,so whats wrong with your query?Maybe show some sample data and the desired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know the distinct years represented in your data, then you probably want something like this:

```
SELECT distinct year(field_id_34) AS year
FROM exp_channel_data
WHERE channel_id = 5
```

I have no idea what field_id_34 is, but I'm inferring from your post that it is a date field. Also, I assume you have reasons for your WHERE filter, although I do not know what those reasons are. But I trust you can fill in those details on your end.